# xlsxwriter: create headings from user input and for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a script that takes user input and outputs an excel file with the user input as the columns headings. 
So if the user inputs: Col1,Col2,Col3 .. the output should be an excel file with 3 columns each name respectively to:  Col1,Col2,Col3.

Code:

```
import xlsxwriter
from itertools import islice
column_names = input()
template_name = input()

  # add file type to template name
file_type = '.xlsx'
template_name = template_name + file_type

  # create a list of the input names
column_names = column_names.split(",")

  # xlsxwriter column position logic based on user input length
alpha = list(map(chr, range(65, 91)))

z =[]

for letter in  alpha:
    z.append(letter + str(1))

t =[]

for i in islice( z, 0, len(column_names) ):
    t.append(i)

  # Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(template_name )
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

  # Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

  # Write some data headers.
for name in column_names:
    for i in t:
        worksheet.write(i,name,bold)
```

Assuming I run the script with an input of : Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
The current output for the script is:  Col5  Col5   Col5   Col5   Col5
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnrgj.png)

The Result I am looking for is: Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlF63.png)

Does anyone know what is wrong with the current script?   Why is that the created excel file has the 5 columns all named  Col5 and not Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5 
Thanks!

Comment: What is the **real** question: you have a list `column_names` holding 5 values: `column_names = ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5']` (you have to check it). Now you want to write the values in the right order to cells A1, B1, C1, D1, E1. Can't be too difficult, can it?

Comment: The script write the values in the right order to cells but it doesn't write the right value. It should write 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5' respectively to  columns  A1, B1, C1, D1, E1.. instead it write  Col5 Col5 Col5 Col5 Col5 respectivelyto  A1, B1, C1, D1, E1

Comment: That is what I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try zip at the end:

```
# Write some data headers.
for i, name in zip(t, column_names):
    worksheet.write(i,name,bold)
```